# Swift 4: 'subscript' is unavailable error

Tags: swift, mapbox, swift4, subscript, swift-subscript

I'm using the MapBox navigation framework that hasn't quite been updated to Swift 4. I have one 'subscript' error that I can't quite get around. Here's the code. I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
private func extractNextChunk(_ encodedString: inout String.UnicodeScalarView) throws -> String {
    var currentIndex = encodedString.startIndex

    while currentIndex != encodedString.endIndex {
        let currentCharacterValue = Int32(encodedString[currentIndex].value)
        if isSeparator(currentCharacterValue) {
            let extractedScalars = encodedString[encodedString.startIndex...currentIndex]
            encodedString = encodedString[encodedString.index(after: currentIndex)..<encodedString.endIndex]

            return String(extractedScalars)
        }

        currentIndex = encodedString.index(after: currentIndex)
    }

    throw PolylineError.chunkExtractingError
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is misleading. The real problem is that subscripting
a `String.UnicodeScalarView` with a range returns a `String.UnicodeScalarView.SubSequence`, so you cannot assign that back to
`encodedString`.

One solution would be to create a `String.UnicodeScalarView` 
from the subsequence:

```
encodedString = String.UnicodeScalarView(encodedString[encodedString.index(after: currentIndex)...])
```

Alternatively (and perhaps simpler) go the other way around and
remove the initial part of `encodedString` instead:

```
encodedString.removeSubrange(...currentIndex)
```

In either case, you can take use "one-sided ranges", compare
[SE-0172](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0172-one-sided-ranges.md)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll give that a test. Could you please add that into the actual code I pasted above? That would be a massive help as I'm not quite 100% sure on your answer. I'm sure it's the solution though

Comment: @ChelsMcKay: Just replace the `encodedString = ...` line which caused the  compiler error.